# NOT LIKE query in MongoDB aggergate

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query in which i would like to implement `not like` query using `aggregate` `$match` and `$regex` .

I want the result to not have `nophoto` in the `image url`.

So the $match query i wrote was

```js
[
  '$match'=>[
    'author.image'=>[
      '$ne'=>[
        '$regex'=>'/nophoto/'
      ]
    ]
  ]
],
```

But still the result is

```js
[
  {
    _id: {
      $oid: "5cc2b26236d94e620335b6a3"
    },
    image: "https://images.gr-assets.com/authors/1397937527p7/46603.jpg"
  },
  {
    _id: {
      $oid: "5cc2b26236d94e620335b6a4"
    },
    image: "https://images.gr-assets.com/authors/1397937527p7/46603.jpg"
  },
  {
    _id: {
      $oid: "5cc2b26236d94e620335b6a5"
    },
    image: "https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/user/u_333x500-46491541e26dbeac15f51487d68dd207.png"
  },
  {
    _id: {
      $oid: "5cc2b26236d94e620335b6a6"
    },
    image: "https://s.gr-assets.com/assets/nophoto/user/u_333x500-46491541e26dbeac15f51487d68dd207.png"
  }
]
```

I want the result set to not have `nophoto` in their image url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [**`$not`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) query to operator to oppose the [**`$regex`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) string.

```
db.collection.find({
  'image': {
    '$not': {
      '$regex': "nophoto"
    }
  }
})
```

In PHP it looks something like this

```
[
  '$match'=>[
    'image'=>[
      '$not'=>[
        '$regex'=>'nophoto'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QEIrDJ1rnGl)

Comment: i actually wanted to use it with `aggregate` .